# How to groupby column headers using a regex?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe like this

```
   S1,0  S1,0.1  S1,0.2  S1,1  S1,1.1  S1,1.2  S2,0  S2,0.1  S2,1  S2,1.1
0     4       0       3     3       3       1     3       2     4       0
1     0       4       2     1       0       1     1       0     1       4
2     3       0       3     0       2       3     0       1     3       3
```

Now I want to `groupby` its column headers whereby `S1,0` should be in one group, `S1,1` in another one, and the same for `S2` and apply certain operations on those groups.

My **expected outcome** looks like this (in case I calculate the `mean`, called `m` and the `standard deviation` called `s`):

```
         S1,0      S1,1      S2,0      S2,1
m 0  2.333333  2.333333  2.500000  2.000000
  1  2.000000  0.666667  0.500000  2.500000
  2  2.000000  1.666667  0.500000  3.000000
s 0  2.081666  1.154701  0.707107  2.828427
  1  2.000000  0.577350  0.707107  2.121320
  2  1.732051  1.527525  0.707107  0.000000
```

I can get this output doing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

data = np.random.randint(0, 5, 30).reshape(3, 10)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['S1,0', 'S1,0.1', 'S1,0.2', 'S1,1', 'S1,1.1', 'S1,1.2',
                                 'S2,0', 'S2,0.1', 'S2,1', 'S2,1.1'])

df = df.T

gdf = df.groupby(lambda x: x.split('.', 1)[0])[df.columns].agg({'m': np.mean, 's': np.std}).T.sort_index()
```

My question is whether there is a way which avoids this `split` operation on the column names but where one can pass an actual regex? So something along the lines

```
import re

reg = re.compile('^S\d,\d')

gdf2 = df.groupby(reg)[df.columns].agg({'m': np.mean, 's': np.std}).T.sort_index()
```

This does not work but is anything comparable possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with `regex`:

```
df = df.T

pat = df.index.str.extract('(^S\d,\d)', expand=False)
print (pat)
Index(['S1,0', 'S1,0', 'S1,0', 'S1,1', 'S1,1', 'S1,1', 'S2,0', 'S2,0', 'S2,1',
       'S2,1'],
      dtype='object')

df = df.groupby(pat).agg(['mean','std'])
       .T
       .swaplevel(0,1)
       .sort_index()
       .rename({'mean':'m','std':'s'})
print (df)
         S1,0      S1,1      S2,0      S2,1
m 0  2.333333  2.333333  2.500000  2.000000
  1  2.000000  0.666667  0.500000  2.500000
  2  2.000000  1.666667  0.500000  3.000000
s 0  2.081666  1.154701  0.707107  2.828427
  1  2.000000  0.577350  0.707107  2.121320
  2  1.732051  1.527525  0.707107  0.000000
```

Another solution without transposing, but `concat` is necessary:

```
pat = df.columns.str.extract('(^S\d,\d)', expand=False)
g = df.groupby(pat, axis=1)
df = pd.concat([g.mean(), g.std()], keys=('m','s'))
print (df)
         S1,0      S1,1      S2,0      S2,1
m 0  2.333333  2.333333  2.500000  2.000000
  1  2.000000  0.666667  0.500000  2.500000
  2  2.000000  1.666667  0.500000  3.000000
s 0  2.081666  1.154701  0.707107  2.828427
  1  2.000000  0.577350  0.707107  2.121320
  2  1.732051  1.527525  0.707107  0.000000
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you don't pass the names `m` and `s` directly to `agg` but call another `rename`?

Comment: No, but it failed for me, I can test it again.

Comment: For latter solution, better to do groupby once and reuse it in pd.concat.

Comment: True, but no idea why it fails actually. In my example it works fine like this, but here I get a `KeyError`.